# Is there anyway to get SVG to render in IE 7 or 8? If not is there a good fall back solution?

Tags: wordpress, internet-explorer, svg

I was just doing some final testing on my site and one of more core components is an interactive map on the home page. I loaded up XP and IE 8 and boom and nothing shows. I now understand that SVG is not supported until IE 9, but I know a lot of my customers are going to be stuck in the dark ages on 7 and 8.

1) Is there a way to have my interactive map work at all in 7 and 8?

2) If not is there any sort of fall backs? so if it does not work then it shows something else?

I am using a premium plugin for Wordpress to generate my map http://codecanyon.net/item/mapsvg-interactive-vector-maps/2547255

Thanks in advance for any help / advice!

Comment: Hi, I'm an authour of mapSVG - it should work in all browsers including ie7-8. Have you mailed me with this question? Also please download an update from CodeCanyon (updates are released almost every week).

Comment: Hi thanks I got it working in the end. The problem was in the way the SVG file was created in Illustrator. Would be awesome if you had some save as / export guidelines for CS6 on the plugin on code canyon. I also have latest from a few weeks ago, will get latest now too. cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So taking a look at Modernizr here and I found this:

https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills

http://code.google.com/p/svgweb/

Modernizr utilizes svgweb, which utilizes a Flash fallback. So how this works if you use Modernizr is that you can check to see if their browser supports svg, if it does not then you can use the svgweb fallback, most people have either Flash or HTML5.

But in any case the Modernizr site shows a list of possible fallbacks, I would recommend the Flash one mentioned above. But you may want to try all of them and see which one works best.

Comment: thanks I will try and give this a go, looks pretty complicated in the quick start guide for me...was hoping it would be literally download a js file, call it in the header and boom it will fix it..

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet there is probably to use a library such as [Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com) to draw with. That will generate VML for the older IE versions and SVG for everyone else. Otherwise you'll most likely need to rely on plugins.